# Async web service call not getting data

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following code for my generic class. This can be used for any of the classes that I pass into the method.

```
public static async Task<T>GetData<T>(string req, bool weather = false)
    {
        string webrequest = string.Format("{0}&{1}", req, !weather ? string.Format("key={0}", MainClass.GoogleAPI) : string.Format("APPID={0}", MainClass.WeatherID));
        var request = WebRequest.Create(webrequest) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        string responseContent = "";

        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        try
        {
            var asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(s =>
                    {
                        var response = (s.AsyncState as WebRequest).EndGetResponse(s);

                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            obj = GeneralUtils.Deserialize<T>(responseContent);
                        }

                }), request);
            return obj;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Deserialiser failed : {0}--{1}", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

The request string contains the likes of this

```
var servercall = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Warrington,UK&destination=Whiston,UK&waypoints=Preston,UK|Dundee,UK";
```

the API key is fine.

What I'm finding is that the response line within the asyncResult is never being hit so just the class being passed in is being returned. The classes are generated using the jsontocsharp website using the examples on the google API website.

Normally, I would not use this code, but this is for a PCL library, so needs to be done this way (unless there is another way to do this synchronously that is).

I am not using JSON.Net for this (application spec forbids anything not part of standard .NET). The tests are running as a console app.

Comment: Why is your method marked as `async Task<T>` when you're not awaiting anything? You're using the APM based pattern here. Im not even sure how this compiles.

Answer (score 3):

Your method does not await a response from `BeginGetResponse`, so it ends straightaway and returns `obj` that is an empty object.

There are many ways of doing this, this is one of them:

```
public static async Task<T> GetData<T>(string req, bool weather = false)
{
    string webrequest = string.Format("{0}&{1}", req, !weather ? string.Format("key={0}", MainClass.GoogleAPI) : string.Format("APPID={0}", MainClass.WeatherID));
    var request = WebRequest.Create(webrequest) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    try
    {
       var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

       using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
          return GeneralUtils.Deserialize<T>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("Deserialiser failed : {0}--{1}", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
       throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: `IAsyncResult` is not an awaitable. It can't be awaited

Comment: I meant "await", not `await` (Note the difference between the english verb "to await" and the c# 5 keyworkd `await` :D )

Comment: Thanks for this. When I've replaced my old code with this and put a break point at the using line, I'm finding that it never hits that break point

Comment: Put another break point inside the `catch`, you must be getting an exception then

Comment: How are you calling this method? Perhaps using the `Task.Result` property?

Comment: The catch breakpoint is never hit either. I'm calling the method using `var route = await ServerRequest.GetData<Directions>(servercall);`

Comment: Are you sure the server is up and waiting to timeout on the request?

Comment: Unless google has decided to take down their services, yes. If I remove the async calls, all data is returned as I would expect.